# Help with understanding logarithmic regression formula

Tags: logarithms, regression

I am using [this tool](http://polynomialregression.drque.net/online.php) to find the logarithmic regression for a data set. The formula it produces for my data set is:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1\ln x 
$$
where 
$$
\beta_0 = 4920.91845908055748609950\\
\beta_1 = 18358.72795143316913560309
$$

I am having trouble understanding how to implement this though... do I run the $\ln$ function on x, and then multiply the result with $\beta_1$, and add to $\beta_0$?

i.e. the way I am implementing this in a spreadsheet is…

> =$\beta_1$*LN(x)+$\beta_0$

This is not yielding the expected results

Comment: I didn't like all the numbers, when we can use a variable instead ;)! To answer your question - the logic makes sense.

Comment: Huh - weird  - maybe that little web tool's graph is visually misleading in that case...

Comment: What were you expecting? In any case why are you using an online website when you have Excel? Also, you can easily check if you are doing it right by computing a function that you know like $y = 10\ln (x) -5$ then see what the website gets..